# Logging Options Samba

Tags: samba

My smb.conf has:

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

However, log per machines are empty:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov 19 12:22 log.192.168.70.2`

However, samba sharing it's working fine.

Why does logging per machine not working?

Versions: samba-4.1.12-24.el7_1.x86_64 on Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable a **module** (*vfs objects*) for the share you want to log, you need to add this in the **`smb.conf`** file.

```
[yourshare]
    ...
    vfs objects = full_audit
    ...
```

An additional thing you have to add in the config file is at the **global** section:

```
[global]
    ...
    # Audit settings 
    full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
    full_audit:failure = all; You can filter the requests. 
    full_audit:success = all; 
    full_audit:facility = local5
    full_audit:priority = notice
    ...
```

Next you have to setup rsyslog, for more information I redirect you to the following [link](http://linux-sys-adm.com/ubuntu-16.04-lts-how-to-configure-samba-full-audit/).

Comment: for the record, as the link you provided, following `First Option – Configuring syslogd` worked for me. The `Second option` which adding `00-samba-audit.conf` didn't work in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

Answer (score 1):

In samba, to capture log, you should use samba audit. Please refer to http://vmassuchetto.github.io/2013/12/10/samba-full_audit-in-ubuntu-1204/. I tested that work fine with both samba3 and samba4

Comment: Link has died. Copy of it from before it died:
https://blog.cadena-it.com/linux-tips-how-to/samba-full_audit-in-ubuntu-12-04/